# Need a solution for the threads deadlock situation in asp.net async controller

Tags: c#, mongodb, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Let's say I have a method calling Mongodb database via .net mongo driver (below-mentioned Collection object is part of its Api):

```
    public virtual Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return Collection.Find(Filter.Empty).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Now I have an async asp.net controller where I want to call this method from. However this example runs into thread deadlock issue, which results in current asp.net thread hangs:

```
public class TestController : AsyncController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TestAction()
    {
         var data = await GetAllAsync<Client>();
         ...
    }
}
```

While this example works fine:

```
public class TestController : AsyncController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TestAction()
    {
         var data = await GetAllAsync<Client>().ConfigureAwait(false);
         ...
    }
}
```

the only difference is `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the latter example.

Should I add this `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere in situations like this, or there is a more elegant solution to the problem?

**UPDATE**:
If I create MVC project from scratch same action methods work fine not getting into deadlock issue. Though if I use old MVC project that I migrated into new MVC, the problem with deadlock occur in the first example. Not sure what the difference is between this two, I opened packaged.config and bin directory and made sure same versions of Microsoft.AspNet.* are used, C# code is the same. The only thing different is old solution has things like StructureMap and Cassette preinstalled, could be some different settings in web.config impacting controller behavior as well.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? it is advised in more recent version to stop using `AsyncController` and instead use `Controller` which has async built in. ie `TestController : Controller`. That could be your problem with the mixing of contexts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721571/should-i-use-asynccontroller-at-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054626/async-await-asynccontroller

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc = 5.2.3, Microsoft.AspNet.Razor = 3.2.3, .net 4.7
Replacing AsyncController by Controller has not fixed first example unfortunately. Thanks

Comment: _[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)_

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigureAwait(false)` cannot be used on action methods because the execution must return to the synchronization context after the `await`.

On any other method `ConfigureAwait(false)` should be used.

If some code is synchronously blocking in an asynchronous method, the whole thing will block.